# No Bib File Found Sublime Text 3 LatexTools

Tags: bibliographies, sublime-text

I'm writing a paper, IEEE style, and I am trying to get the bibliography working. Previously in overleaf when I wanted to use one of the sources in my bibliography, i would do \cite{} and a list of the bibitems would pop up. When I attempt this in sublime text using LatexTools I am running into the issue of "no bib file found". I was wondering if anyone knew of a fix?

An example of my bibliography

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{LSTM}
 Adventures in Machine Learning. (2018). Keras LSTM tutorial - How to easily 
 build a powerful deep learning language model - Adventures in Machine 
 Learning. [online] Available at: 
 http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/keras-lstm-tutorial/ [Accessed 27 
 Apr. 2018].
 \bibitem{BBTT}
 Brownlee, J. (2018). A Gentle Introduction to Backpropagation Through Time. 
 [online] Machine Learning Mastery. Available at: 
 https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-backpropagation- 
 time/ [Accessed 27 Apr. 2018].
 \bibitem{textbook}
 Goodfellow, I., Bengio, Y. and Courville, A. (n.d.). Deep learning.
 \bibitem{effective}
 Karpathy.github.io. (2018). The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent 
 Neural Networks. [online] Available at: 
 http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ [Accessed 27 Apr. 
 2018].

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: LaTeXTools currently only supports bib files and no inline bibliography. If you have issues with LaTeXTools please create an issue on [github](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues)