# ST3: no bib files found in a subfile

Tags: biblatex, subfiles, sublime-text

This could be a duplicate of [No Bib File Found Sublime Text 3 LatexTools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430569/no-bib-file-found-sublime-text-3-latextools) but I'm wondering if a solution was found for this?

I'm writing my thesis in Sublime Text 3 on Win10. The LatexTools package is installed, the distro is TexLive and the builder invokes latexmk.
I structured my work so that I have the main `Thesis.tex` root file which uses `subfiles` and lets `Ch1.tex` etc. piggyback preamble + bibliography from the main file. The root document is located at the base level in the working directory, while the bibliography (Bib), figures (Fig) and chapters (Tex) are in their own subfolders.

Trouble is the subfiles cannot seem to fetch `.bib` files linked in the root document despite using the `\subfix` command. Upon writing \parencite and opening the first {} bracket I get a Sublime Text error "No bib files found".

MWE

```
%Thesis.tex
\addbibresource{Bib/Mendeley/Alkaline Rx & Carbonatites.bib}
\addbibresource{Bib/Mendeley/eBooks & Theses.bib}
\addbibresource{Bib/Mendeley/Fluid Processes.bib}
\addbibresource{Bib/Mendeley/Geosoftware stuff.bib}
\addbibresource{Bib/Mendeley/Miscallaneous.bib}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\subfile{Tex/Ch1}
...
\end{document}

%Ch.1.tex
\documentclass[../Thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{\subfix{../Fig/Final/}}}

\addbibresource{{\subfix{../Bib/Mendeley/Alkaline Rx & Carbonatites.bib}}}
\addbibresource{{\subfix{../Bib/Mendeley/eBooks & Theses.bib}}}
\addbibresource{{\subfix{../Bib/Mendeley/Fluid Processes.bib}}}
\addbibresource{{\subfix{../Bib/Mendeley/Geosoftware stuff.bib}}}
\addbibresource{{\subfix{../Bib/Mendeley/Miscallaneous.bib}}}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

I was hoping to use `subfiles` to let me compile the chapters on their own and the `\subfix` command seems to work fine fetching the graphics, but not the `.bib` files? I thought this was a `biber` issue so changed my distro from MiKTeX to TexLive, but still getting the error described above.

I should add the root document `Thesis.tex` compiles just fine and has all of the bibliography working as intended. Issue persists only with the subfiles. Compiling the subfile also works, but I get warnings of undefined citations.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: OK I messed around a little bit and using Sublime Text's **Basic builder** helps a bit. It worked on my code without me introducing any additional changes and fixes the compilation process.
Traditional builder seems to not work, probably as it doesn't run `biber` on the subfile by default.

The builder compiles the subfile, but does not fix the Sublime Text prompt, and I am yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, your setup is too complicated. Second, you have to make sure that your TeX-IDE runs `biber` in the main directory on `Thesis` and in the `Tex` directory on `Ch1`.

Here is an example that works.

```
% Thesis.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\addbibresource{\subfix{Bib/Mendeley/a.bib}}% <<< Use subfix here
\addbibresource{\subfix{Bib/Mendeley/b.bib}}% <<< Use subfix here
\graphicspath{{Fig/Final}}% <<< Set the graphicspath in the main file for the main as well as the subfiles
\begin{document}
\cite{aaa,bbb}
\includegraphics{img.jpg} % loads Fig/Final/img.jpg
\subfile{Tex/Ch1}
\end{document}

% Tex/Ch1
\documentclass[../Thesis]{subfiles}
\begin{document}% <<< NO NEED TO SET graphics path AND bib resources
\section{In the subfile}
\cite{aaa,bbb}
\includegraphics{img} % loads ../Fig/Final/img.jpg
\end{document}
```

To compile `Thesis.tex`, go to the main directory and run

```
pdflatex Thesis
biber Thesis
pdflatex Thesis
pdflatex Thesis
```

To compile `Ch1.tex`, change to the directory `Tex` and run

```
pdflatex Ch1
biber Ch1
pdflatex Ch1
pdflatex Ch1
```

If you use an IDE, make sure that it does it for you. If you don't know how to configure the tool, ask a specific question on that, with the details of your TeX environment.

Comment: Can you clarify what is complicated about the setup?

Comment: I am conscious of the compilation order. I was hoping for some help to troubleshoot the ST3 "no bib file prompt" upon inserting a command in the subfile. The document compiles correctly when Basic builder is used.

Comment: @Wolfe79 "Can you clarify what is ..." I'm referring to the way how you define the bib resources. In your example, the `\subfix` in the subfile doesn't do anything, as the preamble of the subfile is only executed when running LaTeX directly on the subfile. But in this case, `\subfix` is void. On the other hand, the  addbibresources in the main file are always executed, but they point nowhere when typesetting the subfile, because `\subfix` is missing. The same holds for graphicspath.

Comment: As I understand `\subfix` ought to be included in the subfiles rather than the root document as it's designed to point the subfile in the child directory to the `bib` and `jpg` files in their own directories?
I re-built each document (pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex) having replaced the relative file paths in the addbibresource and graphicspath commands with absolute ones. Still the "no bib files found" prompt persists unless I place the
`%! TEX root = Thesis.tex` at the top of each file. But that forces the builder to compile the main file instead of the subfile...

Comment: @Wolfe79 No, `\subfix` has to be used with any relative path, no matter whether main or subfile, except in `\graphicspath` and `\bibliography`, where the `subfiles` package adds `\subfix` automatically. Moreover, the idea is to have path and file specifications only in one place, typically the main preamble, and to specify each path relative to the file where it appears in.