# Bibliography imported from main and subfiles

Tags: biblatex, packages, import, subfiles

I have a bib file that I need several subfiles to have access to. Currently the file structure is:

```
project
   main.tex
   Bib.bib
       Chapters
           Chapter1
               Chapter1.tex
```

I can run either the main.tex and have the bib display correctly using`\addbibresource{Bib.bib}` or I can have the subfiles (in this case Chapter1.tex) run correctly by having `\addbibresource{../../Bib.bib}` in the main.tex file. How can I have both documents run without having to change the code in main.tex each time or without using the full directory?

I understand for images and other documents the correct tool would be the import package described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files) question but that doesn't appear to work correctly with biblatex.

Comment: Are you using the `subfiles` class/package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles)? In that case you should look into the `\subfix` command. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594132/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585217/35864.

Comment: @moewe Works perfectly thanks. I'll let you write an answer for the rep if you'd like otherwise I'll write an answer myself later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile your included files also as standalone documents, you need something more than just `\input` or `\include`.

One solution that generally works well with `biblatex` is [`subfiles`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles), which has the magic command `\subfix` to fix file path mismatches caused by different working directories.

[ST3: no bib files found in a subfile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594132/35864) and [When using subfiles package, where it the proper location to add the bibliography files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585217/35864) have elaborate examples, so suffice it to say here that
it is probably enough to use `.bib` file names relative to the main `.tex` document wrapped in `\subfix`, e.g.

```
\addbibresource{\subfix{Bib.bib}}
```